# Posting data to facebook from my web application without users having to authenticate with facebook

Tags: facebook

I have a web application where users can add recommendations , post comments etc .

I would like to give users the ability to post this data on facebook directly from my application .

I can use fbConnect and have them authenticate with facebook for every session whenever they want to post data . 

However , I would like to avoid that .

I would like to make it such that they need to authenticate just once ( and not every session )  with facebook .And after that whenever they make some changes in my application ,it should go automatically to facebook ( without them having to do the facebook authentication ) .

I know this is possible as twitter does it , but am not able to find any documentation on facebook regarding this. It seems that whenever you want to interact with facebook , you need the session key and thus need to get your users authenticated .

How to do this ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to request the `publish_stream` and `offline_access` permissions, which will allow you to use the Graph API to post on their behalf at any time.